# How to insert link in this code

Tags: button, hyperlink, insert, href

How to insert a href link to this code ?

```
<a class="button button_center" style="text-align: center;">Discover Now</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **href="Your URL here"**  inside anchor tag

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/" class="button button_center" tyle="text-align: center;">Discover Now</a>
```